# Generating structured maps with test.check

Tags: clojure, test.check

I'm playing around with test.check, and I'm testing a function which takes a map as an argument. These maps do have a defined structure, such as:

```
{:name "Bob" :age 42 :email "bob@example.com" :admin true}
```

Key point, there is a set of expected keys, the values of which have differing clearly defined generators.

I took a look at `gen/map`, but it's not obvious how to use it for more structured key/value pairs:

```
(gen/sample (gen/map gen/keyword gen/boolean) 5)
;; => ({} {:z false} {:k true} {:v8Z false} {:9E false, :3uww false, :2s true})
```

This seems like a simple scenario, but I [can't](https://github.com/clojure/test.check/blob/master/README.md) [find](https://github.com/clojure/test.check/blob/master/doc/intro.md) [an example](https://github.com/clojure/test.check/blob/master/doc/generator-examples.md).

How can I generate structured maps, such as the one described here, using test.check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`gen/hash-map`](http://clojure.github.io/test.check/clojure.test.check.generators.html#var-hash-map) instead of [`gen/map`](http://clojure.github.io/test.check/clojure.test.check.generators.html#var-map).

```
=> (gen/sample (gen/hash-map :name gen/string
                             :age gen/int
                             :email email-gen     ; from test.check examples
                             :admin gen/boolean))
({:email "00w@hotmail.com", :age 0, :name "", :admin true}
 {:email "mi6@computer.org", :age -1, :name "Á6", :admin false}
 {:email "Ux4gp@hotmail.com", :age 4, :name "z", :admin true})
```